# Drawing into scrollView

Tags: android

my problem I know is simple, but for the life of me I cant get an answer...

I have a LinearLayout that got a scrollview inside it... in the scroll view (in code) it should call a custom ScrollView to show on the application... it only shows black, nothing in it... here is my code

first the xml... simple LL with a textview, scrollview and button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/textView1" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="test field" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>           

<ScrollView android:layout_width="600dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:id="@+id/v1"
android:fillViewport="true"/>

<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/gfx"
android:text="Gfx" 
></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the onCreate of that activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    cw = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    ch = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    v = Draw2d findViewById(R.id.v1);

    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.gfx);

    mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

}
```

Draw2d is the class of the custom scrollView declared like so (it does have onDraw and everything. If I set the contentview to the Draw2d object directly it'll show no problem, but I need it withen a LL)

```
public static class Draw2d extends ScrollView{  
        public Draw2d(Context context) {
            super(context);

        }
```

Please any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because of you have nothing in the ScrollView? Try putting something in it. Check [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example) link, you see there is another linear layout in the scrollview with "30px" layout height making the scrollview appear. If the layout_height was wrap_content, you would not see the scrollview if there is enough place on the screen for it.

Comment: I do have, there is an onDraw function in the custom scrollView that i did not paste here. but it does show correctly if I do setContentView directly as the class Draw2d... but I dont want that, _i want to set the XML layout